# How to make my FreePascal app exit with a specific code if a certain exception is thrown?

Tags: exception, pascal, freepascal, exit-code

My program has an `ESyntaxError` class that I use like this:

```pascal
raise ESyntaxError.Create(Message)
```

And I have that `ESyntaxError` class just defined like this:

```pascal
ESyntaxError = class(Exception)
```

I observe that if that `ESyntaxError.Create(Message)` code has been called, my program’s exit code gets set to `1`. But what I would like to have it set to instead in this case is `65`.

I have tried just doing this:

```pascal
ExitCode := 65;
raise ESyntaxError.Create(Message);
```

...But with that my app still just exits with `1`, not `65`—I guess because the built-in `Exception` class always resets `ExitCode` to `1`? (Don’t know for sure that’s the case and have seen nothing in [the Exception docs](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/exception.html) explicitly stating that, but I infer that from the behavior I’ve observed here).

Or if I want to end up with the program having a non-`1`/non-`0` exit status, should I perhaps be handling this in some other way than basing it on `Exception`?

Comment: For console application it works fine. For GUI application the simplest way is to use `TApplicationProperties` components (Additional page) and its `OnException` event to catch unhandled exceptions. Write something like `if E is ESyntaxError then Halt(65) else raise E;` inside it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works: you can wrap main routine in try-except block, then assign ExitCode for specific types of exceptions

```
program project1;

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  EMy = class(Exception);

procedure run;
begin
  raise EMy.Create('lel');
end;

begin
  try
    run;
  except
    on e: EMy do
    begin
      ExitCode := 65;
    end;
  end;
end.
```